# Bootstrap 5 album grid with different text lengths. Make them homogeneous

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap album similar to the following:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/album/

But the texts that I show have different lengths. So my result is something like this:

[image]

I would like to make my elements homogeneous, with the same sizes, in the more responsive possible way.
Ideally using a property similar to text-overflow with a max length.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?
if so, you can customize the height size in the card-text class

`<p class="card-text overflow-hidden" style="max-height: 10vh">`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card max-height-50 shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text overflow-hidden" style="max-height: 10vh">
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
              </p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
               <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text overflow-hidden" style="max-height: 10vh">
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
              </p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text overflow-hidden" style="max-height: 10vh">
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
              </p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- Boostrap Bundle file -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Same with ellipsis instead of hidden?

Comment: There are many solutions, you can use max-height with overflow-hidden as above or text-truncate but it only shows the first line. If you want to show more characters and you don't want to use max-height and overflow-hidden you can use Javascript  code for handling this situation.